# Making a button toggle a div's class

Tags: javascript, class, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making some basic site with Twitter Bootstrap

I have one div and two classes I want to use.
I want to implement button which will change div's class and then after clicking again, to change it back.

Found many ways, but none of them changes class back.
The Best way would be to use Bootstrap JS or Jquery

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo 1: http://jsfiddle.net/Jsqh4/
Demo 2 (separate button): http://jsfiddle.net/Jsqh4/1/

Bootstrap uses jQuery for its components, so a jQuery solution is probably easiest for you.

```
<style>
    .style1{ background-color: yellow; }
    .style2{ background-color: green; }​
</style>

<div id="div1" class="style1">
    Here is a div.
</div>

<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Click Me" />

<script>
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#div1").toggleClass("style2");
    });
</script>
```

See also: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: is it possible to do same on <ul> element?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment on accepted answer unfortunately...

I would toggle both classes to avoid any risks of missing some styles that aren't overwritten.

```
<style>
    .style1{ background-color: yellow; }
    .style2{ background-color: green; }​
</style>

<div id="div1" class="style1">
    Here is a div.
</div>

<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Click Me" />

<script>
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#div1").toggleClass("style1");
        $("#div1").toggleClass("style2");
    });
</script>
```